# Movie with guy travelling through some kind of teleport gates to other worlds

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find the name of this movie, but I don't remember much of it.

What I remember is just that there was this guy that kept travelling through some teleport gates and fighting some guys. I think time-travel was also involved, as this guy one time met either himself in the future or past, or a clone of his.

I remember a specific scene, in which he met one of his clones and then some bad guys appeared and they kept fighting them but they lost. And then the bad guys were trying to figure out who the real guy was from the two and they kept telling that the other one of them is the real version.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this movie, and do you think it might've been made?

Comment: @LogicDictates I think I saw it on TV roughly around 2007-2008. As for when the movie might have been made, around 2002-2003 I guess.

Comment: What were the other worlds like? Were any set in clearly different time periods, or on different planets? Or was it more like the TV show, _[Sliders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliders)_, were they were just travelling to alternate present-day Earths?

Comment: How do they fight? Unarmed combat? Swords? Guns? Psychic blasts? Aggressive debate?

Comment: Protagonist Asian?  "Multiverse cops" chasing the jumper?

Comment: @LogicDictates, I don't think they were travelling to alternate Earths. I think they were other planets, as I remember some beings that resembled humans, but they were definitely not humans.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots in the scene I mentioned above, while they were on another world or planet, they were fighting unarmed.

Comment: @ZeissIkon, hmm, there were some people that were chasing this guy across the worlds, but I don't remember if they were `cops` or if he was `asian`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have a strong hunch this is *The One* — a Jet Li vehicle from 2001.

There are many Earths (the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics applies), and it's possible to travel between them if you have the technology to detect the wormholes that intermittently connect one to another.  Each Earth (usually) has a duplicate of any given person — but if one or more of the duplicates is killed, the remaining ones become "more" — stronger, smarter, faster — in proportion to the dead vs. still living.

Jet Li plays a man who has noticed that he's getting these benefits, but without any idea why: it turns out one of the copies of him has found out about this power concentration and started jumping worlds and killing his other selves.

A couple of (rather outclassed, by the time they get on the trail) "cops" whose job is to prevent just this get onto the job, and wind up recruiting Jet Li's protagonist to help capture the other one, whose goal is to become "The One" — the only remaining example of himself, with all the power and skill of the two-hundred-plus originals concentrated into a single being.

Comment: Yes, this is the movie I was looking for. Thank you!